# How to access JS-Object elements with getSelectedRecords()-function provided by Syncfusion

Tags: angular, typescript, syncfusion

I am new to this platform. I appreciate any kind of answer and if I am mistaken or if I violate any rules of this platform, do not hesitate to point it out.

I work with the Angular-Framework (7. version) and syncfusion to built a web-application. I receive data via API and with functions provided by Syncfusion I can access the index of the row (of a table) and its records.

So, I wondered whether you can get an element (its value) of an JS-Object by using the getSelectedRecords function provided by Syncfusion.

Sadly, I am not in the enviroment, where I code but I ask myself how to do that, if it is actually possible.

So I searched for an example code of the official documentation by Syncfusion, which looks like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-container',
    template: <ejs-grid #grid [dataSource]='data' height='315px' 
(rowSelected)='rowSelected($event)'>
                <e-columns>
                    <e-column field='OrderID' headerText='Order ID' 
textAlign='Right' width=120></e-column>
                    <e-column field='CustomerID' headerText='Customer ID' 
width=150></e-column>
                    <e-column field='ShipCity' headerText='Ship City' 
width=150></e-column>
                    <e-column field='ShipName' headerText='Ship Name' 
width=150></e-column>
                </e-columns>
               </ejs-grid>
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

public data: Object[];

@ViewChild('grid')
public grid: GridComponent;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data = data;
}

rowSelected(args: RowSelectEventArgs) {
    let selectedrowindex: number[] = this.grid.getSelectedRowIndexes();  // Get the selected row indexes.
    alert(selectedrowindex); // To alert the selected row indexes.
    let selectedrecords: Object[] = this.grid.getSelectedRecords();  // Get the selected records.
}
}
```

In the last line of the function rowSelected, you see that the Records of the Object are stored in an Object[] type. Using the console.log function I saw that the records were stored in an Object as well, and Objects are accessable. Instead of using getSelectedRecords() and store it in an Object, could I expand the function to access the Object and get an element or rather its value and store it in a variable with type of the element?

Appending the function with a "." and write the elements name aside `this.grid.getSelectedRecords().elementsname` won't work but is there something similiar?

I hope that I clearly explained my problem. If anything is unclear, please ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the selected row elements by using the `this.grid.selectionModule.selectedRecords` property and you can get the particular value of the selected records by using the selected row index as below.

```
rowSelected(args:rowSelectedEventArgs){      
      let selectedRowIndex: number[] = this.grid.getSelectedRowIndexes();
      let selectedRowEle: number = (this.grid.getSelectedRecords()[0] as any).OrderID // Get the selected record value using "getSelectedRecords()" 
      let selectedRowElement: Element[] = this.grid.selectionModule.selectedRecords;    // Get the Selected record row element collection.  
    }
```

Refer the [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ukbgus-yfbtqi?file=local-data.component.ts) for more information.

Please get back to us, if you need further assistance.